# remove power from one of laptop's usb hubs

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive

my laptop (hp probook 4530s - windows 8.1 x64) has 4 usb hubs; I attached 1TB external hard-drive to one of them and it works just fine;

if i set the external hard-drive to offline mode then it's corresponding partition goes away and user no longer has access to it; but the external hard-drive still has it's power(it's led is on);

is there anyway to disable the power of that usb hub that external hard-drive is attached to it?(I want to remove power from external hard-drive without physically detach it from laptop)

Comment: Can I ask why you want this?

Answer (score 0):

No. Unless you build a switch into your USB cable and turn that off by hand after removing the drive safely on your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think you can.

Go to device manager and disable the USB

You will have to work out which USB root hub corresponds to which USB port on your machine, but this should work.

Failing that, the expensive option is to buy a new external drive with a power switch.